# It seems I can't use a regexp with the same character in another regexp with added letters

Tags: python, regex, debugging, arguments

I'm trying to match a regexp with a letter **(D|d)** which works fine. However, the computer misinterprets **(ds|Ds|dS|DS)** for the first regexp **(D|d)** and produces an error in the code because it tries to match with the previous regexp. On the side note, I tried pulling data from excel using (D|d) expression and it works perfectly fine. Is there any documentation on reg exp for python to prevent this from happening?

```
import re 
import pandas as pd

increment_data = pd.read_excel('Bamboo_Database.xlsx', sheet_name='Data_Sheet')  # pulls data from excel

DPattern = r"(D|d)"
DsPattern = r"(ds)|(DS)|(dS)|(Ds)"

y = input("Item #: ")

    if re.match(DPattern, y):  # Diet special dishes
        y = y.replace('d', '')
        y = y.replace('D', '')
        print(increment_data.loc[int(y)-1:int(y)-1, 'Diet_Special_Dishes':'$12'])

    if re.match(DsPattern, y):  # Daily Special
        y = y.replace('ds', '')
        y = y.replace('dS', '')
        y = y.replace('Ds', '')
        y = y.replace('DS', '')
        print(increment_data.loc[int(y)-1:int(y)-1, 'Daily_Special':'$15'])
```

**The error message shows the computer is entering the **first if statement** and only removes the "d"/"D" char.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/Linregression/bamboosales.py", line 47, in 
print(increment_data.loc[int(y)-1:int(y)-1, 'Diet_Special_Dishes':'$12'])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's1'

Comment: If you first replace all the d and D's with an empty string, I don't think the ds or DS pattern will ever match because there are no d's left. Instead of `(ds)|(DS)|(dS)|(Ds)` you could also use `[DS][ds]` or just `ds` with a case insensitive flag

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the insensitive flag. Is there a way where I can xor DS and D from each other using **regex only** or will the computer always read the D first and execute the first if statement?

Comment: You code will process the D first, and then DS. Did you try changing the order of the code? First `if re.match(DsPattern, y)` part and then `if re.match(DPattern, y)` ?

Comment: Learning something new every day! Thank you it works.